# XSLT read file to variable and delete corresponding value in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml:

```
<root>
    <tag1>
        <tag2 id="111" pid="000" name="name1">
            <tag3>xxx</tag3>
            ...more tags...
        </tag2>
        <tag2 id="222" nid="111" name="name2">
            <tag3>yyy</tag3>
            ...more tags...
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
    ...more tags...
</root>
```

And a txt file (name.txt) with list of name values:

```
name1
name3
....
```

Is it possible to have a xslt to read from name.txt, delete the tag2 with name attribute matches list in name.txt. So the output of xml would be:

```
<root>
    <tag1>
        <tag2 id="222" nid="111" name="name2">
            <tag3>yyy</tag3>
            ...more tags...
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
    ...more tags...
</root>
```

Cheers, Li

Comment: XSLT 1.0 cannot read an external text file. Are you able to pass the names as a parameter when initializing the transformation? Or could you modify the text file so that it has at least an XML wrapper?

Comment: Yes, I can add XML wrapper to the test file. How to proceed next? Thanks,

Comment: Good. Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the external file to look like this:

**names.xml**

```
<names>
name1
name3
</names>
```

then you can use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="names-doc" select="'names.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="names" select="str:tokenize(document($names-doc)/names, '&#10;')" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag2">
    <xsl:if test="not(@name = $names)">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This requires an XSLT 1.0 processor such as libxslt, that supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` function.

Comment: Getting "variable references are not allowed in a pattern."

Comment: @dellair That's strange: I have tested it with libxslt and it works for me here. But technically it's correct: try the edited version instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="text-url" select="'name.txt'"/>

<xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($text-url), '\r?\n+')"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="tag2[@name = $names]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Was just about to post the exact same answer. +1 Not sure what I read the first time through the question :-/

Comment: *hugs*, sorry guys, was searching for xslt 1.0. Just modified the question. Could you please advice?